# Remove current text and concatenate with the new letter using click function - vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

I need your help, I am trying to create something in javascript. What I want to achieve is when I try to click the button `1` more than once it would replace the word that says *RESULTS HERE* and would just concatenate the word 1 all over again. Right now its not concatenating. It would only display number 1 once. Please check the code for reference. Your helped would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so Much.

```js
let Result = document.getElementById("result");
Result.innerText = "RESULT HERE";
    
//ONE 
const numberOne = document.querySelector('.one');
numberOne.addEventListener('click', runEvent);
    
function runEvent(e) {
   let numeroUno = "1";
     console.log(e.type);
   Result.innerText = " ";
   Result.innerHTML +=  numeroUno; 
   }
```

```html
 <style>
   p {
     font-size: 23px;
     float: left;
     padding: 30px;
     border: solid #336336 2px;
     margin: 20px;
     }
</style>

<h1 id="result"> </h1>
<p id="1" class="one">1</p>
```

Comment: It works but the RESULT HERE is still there. Is there a way for me to remove the RESULT HERE once I clicked the 1 button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`innerText` is a quirky nonstandard property that IE introduced. It is highly recommended to instead use the standard, quicker, more reliable `textContent` instead - see http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText

Try checking to see if the current `textContent` is the original `'RESULT HERE'`, and if it's not, then add to the existing textContent instead of replacing:

```js
const Result = document.getElementById("result");
Result.textContent = "RESULT HERE";

const numberOne = document.querySelector('.one');
numberOne.addEventListener('click', runEvent);

function runEvent(e) {
  if (Result.textContent === 'RESULT HERE') {
    Result.textContent = '1';
  } else Result.textContent += '1';
}
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 23px;
  float: left;
  padding: 30px;
  border: solid #336336 2px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="result"> </h1>
<p id="1" class="one">1</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much you guys are legends!

Comment: When you see an answer that's helpful for you, please upvote it and Accept it

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to achieve is when I try to click the 1 button more than
>   once it would **replace the word that says RESULTS HERE** and would just
>   **concatenate the word 1** all over again.

You can *remove* `RESULT HERE` **conditionally** and keep concatenating `1`'s

```
function runEvent(e) {
    let numeroUno = "1";
    //console.log(e.type);
    if ( Result.innerHTML == "RESULT HERE" ) 
    {
       Result.innerHTML = "";
    }
    Result.innerHTML +=  numeroUno; 
}
```